# How to use KnockoutJS for adding client side paging to table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

How can I add paging with KnockoutJS?

My current code is:

```
//assuming jsondata is a collection of data correctly passed into this function

myns.DisplayFields = function(jsondata) {
    console.debug(jsondata);
    window.viewModel = {
        fields: ko.observableArray(jsondata),
        sortByName: function() { //plus any custom functions I would like to perform
            this.items.sort(function(a, b) {
                return a.Name < b.Name ? -1 : 1;
            });
        },
    };

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
}
```

My view:

```html
<table>
  <tbody data-bind='template: "fieldTemplate"'></tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/html" id="fieldTemplate">
{{each fields}}
    <tr>
         <td> ${ FieldId }</td>
         <td>${ Type }</td>
         <td><b>${ Name }</b>: ${ Description }</td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
</script>
```

Could or would I use jQuery, jQuery UI or another library?

I have seen on the KnockoutJS site as an example:

```
myModel.gridViewModel = new ko.simpleGrid.viewModel({
    data: myModel.items,
    columns: [
        { headerText: "Item Name", rowText: "name" },
        { headerText: "Sales Count", rowText: "sales" },
        { headerText: "Price", rowText: function (item) { return "$" + item.price.toFixed(2) } }
    ],
    pageSize: 4
});
```

However where would I add pageSize to my code? How is this pageSize internally being run?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The basic idea is that you have a <s>[dependentObservable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/dependentObservables.html)</s> [Computed Observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) that represents the rows in your current page and bind your table to it.  You would slice the overall array to get the rows for the page.  Then, you have pager buttons/links that manipulate the page index, which causes the dependentObservable to be re-evaluated resulting in the current rows.

Based on your code, something like:

```
var myns = {};
myns.DisplayFields = function(jsondata) {
    var viewModel = {
        fields: ko.observableArray(jsondata),
        sortByName: function() { //plus any custom functions I would like to perform
            this.items.sort(function(a, b) {
                return a.Name < b.Name ? -1 : 1;
            });
        },
        pageSize: ko.observable(10),
        pageIndex: ko.observable(0),
        previousPage: function() {
            this.pageIndex(this.pageIndex() - 1);
        },
        nextPage: function() {
            this.pageIndex(this.pageIndex() + 1);
        }
    };

    viewModel.maxPageIndex = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
        return Math.ceil(this.fields().length / this.pageSize()) - 1;
    }, viewModel);

    viewModel.pagedRows = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
        var size = this.pageSize();
        var start = this.pageIndex() * size;
        return this.fields.slice(start, start + size);
    }, viewModel);

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
};
```

So, you would bind your table to `pagedRows`.

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/5Xr2X/

Comment: Thank you, I think I need to look into and understand knockout.js better, I thought it was best to start with a practical example straight up to get used to this library, ah well :)

Comment: The maxPageIndex function is not correct. It should be: Math.ceil(this.fields().length / this.pageSize()) - 1;

Comment: Thanks.  I see where it fails previously.  Updated answer.

Comment: Not completely necessary, but you might want to consider checking the previousPage and nextPage against the limits.  For example: if( this.pageIndex() - 1 >= 0 ){ this.pageIndex(this.pageIndex() - 1); }  

Thanks for the great example!

Comment: I wrote a reusable component that achieves the same here http://blog.greatrexpectations.com/2012/07/11/paging-lists-with-knockout/

Answer (score 2):

Did you achieve what you wanted?

I recently pushed an example of a nice pager using knockout to github.

See https://github.com/remcoros/ko.pager for the source and http://remcoros.github.com/ko.pager/example.html for a working example.

All computations and some convenient properties are provided by the 'Pager' class, which you can create and bind to. An example working template is included.

See the source example.html for some doc and usage.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone.paginator is something for you? From the Github page:

> Backbone.Paginator is a set of opinionated components for paginating collections of data using Backbone.js. It aims to provide both solutions for assisting with pagination of requests to a server (e.g an API) as well as pagination of single-loads of data, where we may wish to further paginate a collection of N results into M pages within a view.

Comment: voted up. haven't looked at bb paginator, but seems viable if you know how to write the glue to knockout.