# Sorting a knockout grid in the client

Tags: javascript, sorting, data-binding, knockout.js, client

I am having trouble with what i think comes basically for free with knockout.

I have a foreach loop, done in knock out, which creates table rows.

Outside of this loop i have the table header, and i want to make the column headers trigger a client side sort.

I have seen the observable array function sort() but i cant seem to get it firing. Following up, is it hard to do ascending / descending sorts?

Comment: Can you post some code what you have tried so far? Maybe in a jsfiddle which shows where have you got stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to implement it with this post. The fiddle had just what I needed, it is a good example of the bindings needed.

[Knockoutjs - Sorting a large observablearray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12743265/knockoutjs-sorting-a-large-observablearray)

I extended it by including a sort direction variable in my model that i toggle when sorting.